# Unable to build Ydlidar ros2 package in ros2 humble on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ros2

I have successfully built the ydlidar sdk and had my X2 running with the SDK test files. I have downloaded the ydlidar_ros2_ws using `git clone https://github.com/YDLIDAR/ydlidar_ros2`.

When I try `colcon build` in the workspace I get lots of errors relating to rclcpp/node.hpp such as

> no matching function for call to 'rclcpp::Node::declare_parameter(const charge [15])'

There are too many to list. Why is this happening? Is there any way to fix it?

I was wondering if this version is for another flavour of ros2. If so is there a URL that will work with my software?

I tried looking for other versions of the ydlidar ros2 package but this seems to be the official one.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
I'm using ros2 humble
The error is solved by using humble branch of ydlidar_ros2_driver.
I used this command for cloning

```
git clone -b humble https://github.com/YDLIDAR/ydlidar_ros2_driver.git
```